# How to construct the matrix like this

Tags: matlab

"We consider an unstructured planar
(undirected) graph and calculate the stationary probability distribution of the random
walk on the graph. The graph is generated by choosing n random points in the unit
square and triangulating them using Delaunay triangulation."

This sentence is from the description of a test problem in one article, I want to use this test problem, but I don't konw how to construct the matrix corresponding to this graph by Matlab.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix that corresponds to the "stationary probability distribution of the random walk on the graph" is the *graph Laplacian*. Wikipedia has a long article on it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix

Comment: But, how can i construct by matlab according to the last sentence "The graph is generated by choosing n random points in the unit square and triangulating them using Delaunay triangulation"

Comment: Which part of the sentence is difficult? Choosing the points or the Delaunay triangulation? What have you done so far?

Comment: when i use tri=delaunay([1,2,3]',[5,7,8]')
answer is
tri =

     2     1     3 , this is a vector, how to get a graph matrix.

Comment: This is a question for the help function of matlab.